# Sql Grouping 3 rows of 5 minutes into a single one of 15 minutes

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, intervals

I want to Group 3 rows of 5 minutes into a single one of 15 minutes and be able to do an update on the 3 row if I want.

Here's an example:

```
2016-07-29 14:00:00.000     2016-07-29 14:05:00.000
2016-07-29 14:05:00.000     2016-07-29 14:10:00.000
2016-07-29 14:10:00.000     2016-07-29 14:15:00.000
2016-07-29 14:15:00.000     2016-07-29 14:20:00.000
2016-07-29 14:20:00.000     2016-07-29 14:25:00.000
2016-07-29 14:25:00.000     2016-07-29 14:30:00.000
2016-07-29 14:30:00.000     2016-07-29 14:35:00.000
2016-07-29 14:35:00.000     2016-07-29 14:40:00.000
2016-07-29 14:40:00.000     2016-07-29 14:45:00.000
2016-07-29 14:45:00.000     2016-07-29 14:50:00.000
2016-07-29 14:50:00.000     2016-07-29 14:55:00.000
2016-07-29 14:55:00.000     2016-07-29 15:00:00.000
2016-07-29 15:00:00.000     2016-07-29 15:05:00.000
```

And the result should be :

```
2016-07-29 14:00:00.000     2016-07-29 14:15:00.000
2016-07-29 14:15:00.000     2016-07-29 14:30:00.000
2016-07-29 14:30:00.000     2016-07-29 14:45:00.000
2016-07-29 14:45:00.000     2016-07-29 15:00:00.000
...
```

Thank you! :)

Comment: will they always be in sequence,also please tag the Relevant RDBMS

Comment: SQL Server and want do you mean by sequence ?

Comment: I think he means in the same chronological order

Comment: "and be able to do an update on the 3 row if I want" please explain what you mean by this.

Comment: It means that I have a table with interval of 5 min. If a customer take a appointement of 15 minutes I have to found 3 row together (13:00,13:05),(13:05,13:10),(13:10,13:15) and then update the 3 rows  to be reserved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you want to truncate each time to 15-minute intervals and use that for aggregation.  Something like this:

```
select distinct dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, 0, col1) / 15 * 15, 0),
       dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, 0, col1) / 15 * 15 + 15, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a UDF to create dynamic Date Ranges.  You could also use a number/tally table

```
Declare @Date1 DateTime = '2016-07-29 14:00:00.000'
Declare @Date2 DateTime = '2016-07-30 00:00:00.000'

Select DateR1=RetVal,DateR2=DateAdd(MI,15,RetVal) from [dbo].[udf-Create-Range-Date](@Date1,@Date2,'MI',15) Where RetVal<@Date2
```

Returns

```
DateR1                  DateR2
2016-07-29 14:00:00.000 2016-07-29 14:15:00.000
2016-07-29 14:15:00.000 2016-07-29 14:30:00.000
2016-07-29 14:30:00.000 2016-07-29 14:45:00.000
2016-07-29 14:45:00.000 2016-07-29 15:00:00.000
2016-07-29 15:00:00.000 2016-07-29 15:15:00.000
... 
2016-07-29 23:30:00.000 2016-07-29 23:45:00.000
2016-07-29 23:45:00.000 2016-07-30 00:00:00.000
```

**

> The UDF - Notice you can Ranges, Date Part, and Increment are
>   Parameters

**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Create-Range-Date] (@DateFrom datetime,@DateTo datetime,@DatePart varchar(10),@Incr int)

Returns 
@ReturnVal Table (RetVal datetime)

As
Begin
    With DateTable As (
        Select DateFrom = @DateFrom
        Union All
        Select Case @DatePart
               When 'YY' then DateAdd(YY, @Incr, df.dateFrom)
               When 'QQ' then DateAdd(QQ, @Incr, df.dateFrom)
               When 'MM' then DateAdd(MM, @Incr, df.dateFrom)
               When 'WK' then DateAdd(WK, @Incr, df.dateFrom)
               When 'DD' then DateAdd(DD, @Incr, df.dateFrom)
               When 'HH' then DateAdd(HH, @Incr, df.dateFrom)
               When 'MI' then DateAdd(MI, @Incr, df.dateFrom)
               When 'SS' then DateAdd(SS, @Incr, df.dateFrom)
               End
        From DateTable DF
        Where DF.DateFrom < @DateTo
    )

    Insert into @ReturnVal(RetVal) Select DateFrom From DateTable option (maxrecursion 32767)

    Return
End

-- Syntax Select * from [dbo].[udf-Create-Range-Date]('2016-10-01','2020-10-01','YY',1) 
-- Syntax Select * from [dbo].[udf-Create-Range-Date]('2016-10-01','2020-10-01','DD',1) 
-- Syntax Select * from [dbo].[udf-Create-Range-Date]('2016-10-01','2016-10-31','MI',15) 
-- Syntax Select * from [dbo].[udf-Create-Range-Date]('2016-10-01','2016-10-02','SS',1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Recursive CTE..

<kbd>[DEMO HERE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/519273/interval-grouping)</kbd>

```
    ;With cte(sdate,edate,maxdate)
    as
    (
    select min(sdate),dateadd(minute,15,min(sdate) ),max(edate) as maxdate from #tt 
    union all
    select dateadd(minute,15,sdate),dateadd(minute,15,edate) ,maxdate
     from 
     cte
     where 
     edate<=maxdate
    )
   select sdate,edate from cte
```